# How to generate column numbers and display them on html using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie in JavaScript. I want to generate some numbers and display the whole on html element.

Bellow is the code I wrote. I'm only getting a single number generated on html but I'm getting what I want on the console.

```js
  var b;
  function gen(){
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     b = Math.random().toString();
     console.log(b);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = b;
   };
  }
```

```html
<h1>Generate Phone numbers</h1>
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="Generate" class="btn" onclick="gen()">
  <p>
  <span id="output"></span>
```

Please how do I get what is exactly on the console to  html when I click generate button?

Thanks you

Comment: `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = b;` probably want that to be `+= b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML` method:

```js
var b;
function gen(){
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 b = Math.random().toString();      
 document.getElementById('output').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', b);
};
}
```

```html
<h1>Generate Phone numbers</h1>
<p>
 <input type="button" value="Generate" class="btn" onclick="gen()">
<p>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really worked well. Can you please tell me more about ".insertAdjacentHTML()" function and ""beforeend". Having read many JS books, this is the firsts time I am seeing it. Thanks

Comment: MDN, or Mozilla Developer Network, is a great source for documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

Add a temporary variable to the outside of the loop. Then assign that value to the innerHTML of your span tag.

```js
var phoneNumber = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     b = Math.random().toString();
     console.log(b);
    phoneNumber += b;
   };
document.getElementById("output").value = phoneNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you for you anwer. But The output did not show in the HTML when I ran it but shows in the console. Is there something that I didn't get right.  Thanks a lot